How can you use regex to find a dynamic string that is not preceded by something? (negative lookbehind fails)
Here are some strings (not lines!) that I need to match. (The dots represent other strings that will not match.)
... ThisIsAString ...
... AnotherString ...

Here are some strings that I need to avoid:
... [TEST:ThisIsAString] ...
... TEST:AnotherString ...

These strings are not static and will be different every time.
This is the regex I have right now:
(?<!TEST:)[a-zA-Z]{5,}(?!\])

The silly part is that it will match the first one like hisIsAStrin and the second like notherString when I do not want either of them to match.
What am I missing?
This will be used with both grep and sed to replace the strings with modified versions. (I cannot just use sed.)

sed regex does not support lookarounds

sed 's/S/\n&\n/g; s/\(A\)\n\(S\)\n\(B\)/\1\2\3/g; s/\nS\n/R/g'

Add \b before [a-zA-Z], that will ensure your match doesn't begin in the middle of a word

If you want to use lookarounds then use perl instead of sed

I was unaware of the \b (word boundary). While that did help initially, it is not enough for what I am trying to do. I will need to write a program to look through everything line by line programmatically and take out or ignore the "TEST:" sections beforehand.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E 's/(TEST: ?)(ThisIsAString|AnotherString) /\1\n\2/
        s/ (ThisIsAString|AnotherString) /X&X/;s/\n//' file

The trick is to introduce some scaffolding and use it to match or not match the required string(s) and then remove it before printing the line.
As sed normally reads in a line at time the newline character will never appear and thus it can be used as a separator and safely removed again without affecting the original line.
N.B. There is no need to employ grep with sed as sed is powerful enough to do both jobs. However sed does not employ all the modern regexp that perl etc have at their disposal and might not be the most easily used tool.

I should have clarified that "ThisIsAString" and "AnotherString" are not static; the strings will be different every time, so your solution will not work for me. Also, I need to do something with the strings before reinserting them. I assume you cannot use a different command (like openssl) on those strings while using only sed.
